# jQuery DataTables error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'fnInit' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '**fnInit**' of undefined

**jquery.dataTables.js:2872**

```
DataTable.ext.oPagination[ oSettings.sPaginationType ].fnInit( oSettings, nPaginate, 
                function( oSettings ) {
                    _fnCalculateEnd( oSettings );
                    _fnDraw( oSettings );
                }
            );
```

Table is placed properly, I think, that problem is not in HTML.

Comment: a fiddle would be helpful

Comment: You JS library that 'fnInit' call suppose to invoke seems to be not included in your code

Comment: I had the same cause as @rrsuh - I had "bootstrap" instead of a valid numbers in my datatable setup: `"sPaginationType": "bootstrap",` - changing it to `"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",` solved it for me.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### CAUSE

It seems that the problem is that you used not supported value for [`sPaginationType`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options) or [`pagingType`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType) option.

#### SOLUTION

**DataTables 1.10**

Option [`pagingType`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType) supports the following values by default:

- `numbers` - Page number buttons only (1.10.8+)
- `simple` - 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons only
- `simple_numbers` - 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons, plus page numbers
- `full` - 'First', 'Previous', 'Next' and 'Last' buttons
- `full_numbers` - 'First', 'Previous', 'Next' and 'Last' buttons, plus page numbers

**DataTables 1.9**

Option [`sPaginationType`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options)  supports the following values by default:

- `two_button`- 'Previous' and 'Next'
- `full_numbers` - 'First', 'Previous', 'Next' and 'Last' buttons, plus page numbers

Comment: Hello @Gyrocode.com I'm using 1.10 ```datatable```,  is ```input``` not supported by ```pagingType``` ? I'm trying to display a jump to page input field.

Comment: @natsumiyu, `input` is extra option that is not supported by default. You will need to include extra JS file to add support for `input` pagination type. Please see [`input`](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/input) plug-in for more information.